# What problems might somebody encounter when trying to use the Breit-Wheeler process to produce positron gas?

Tags: particle-physics, photons, electrons, antimatter

Let's take a hypothetical an experimental scenario where a stream of high-energy photons from a powerful source is directed via a system of mirrors and lenses in a two coherent rays to a vacuum camera.

The photons collide in the vacuum camera, producing positron-electron pairs. The pairs are promptly separated before the annihilation by two coils, which lead into two vacuum tubes, that serve as entrances to electromagnetic toroidal containment units that "speed up" the particles, and prevent them from touching the walls of the units.

What kind of problems would prevent such a setup from working as intended?

Comment: See under https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breit%E2%80%93Wheeler_process to. the production of pairs is very inefficient, so why do it this way?

Comment: But what does lead to the inefficiency of the process?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Breit-Wheeler process](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breit%E2%80%93Wheeler_process), in which two photons in vacuum produce an electron-positron pair, has a very low [cross section](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross_section_(physics)).  This low probability of interaction means that nearly all of your photon beam would pass unscathed through your interaction region into some beam dump. Nearly all of the energy in your photon beam would be wasted.

If you want to make positrons, it's much more efficient to point a high-energy electron beam at a thin piece of some dense material like lead or tungsten. The electrons lose energy by scattering from the nuclei and electrons in the matter, emitting [bremsstrahlung photons](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bremsstrahlung).  These photons in turn interact with the virtual photons in the strong electric fields inside the atoms of the material, producing electron-positron pairs.  The net product is a cone of electrons, positrons, and photons, with the particle number reaching some maximum at a calculable depth into the material and the energy being completely absorbed deeper in. To get the most positrons out, you just make the thickness of your material equal to the depth of the maximum particle number.

When I used this technique to increase the signal from giga-eV electrons in a Cherenkov detector, we used lead radiators and settled on a thickness of about an inch. I remember this increased our Cherenkov signal (that is, the total number of charged leptons) by a factor of about eight. You could do better than this if your actual goal were to produce positrons; our interest was the GeV electrons.

Once you have your positrons, you can separate them from the electrons as you describe.  For a wealth of technical details, look for papers from the ALPHA experiment at CERN, which combined a cloud of cold (!) positrons with cold (!!) antiprotons to make antihydrogen atoms.